# How to access port 6001 over HTTPs on apache server

Tags: reactjs, laravel, apache, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I'm currently using laravel-echo-server and websockets (socket.io) to broadcast events to my React application that is on a separate server.

As far as it looks, everything set up on the back end and front end are correct. The only issue I'm running into is not being able to connect to websockets (https://api.mysite.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket). I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I'm trying to figure out how I can allow a user to hit port 6001 over HTTPs on an apache server.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` usually means that port is closed by firewall in the server side, so ask server sysadmin about it to unblock it

Comment: @masterguru I am the sysadmin as well. Whenever I run ufw status, it appears that the port is already open:

6001/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
6001                       ALLOW       Anywhere 
6001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6) 
6001/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: what version of socket.io are you using.

Comment: Then try to telnet that port from that client machine:  `telnet api.mysite.com 6001` and see if it connects.  If yes then I was wrong.  If not then you should fix this issue, that could be firewall again (check client side too) or maybe the service is not running (also check PORT status with `netstat -anp | grep 6001` to know if it in LISTEN status in server machine)

Comment: Did you use `ProxyPass`? If yes, provide the configs you had done.

Comment: @s.abbaasi `ProxyPass        /socket.io http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/`

Comment: @pbrune remove the last / and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i made it works was the following:

**Step 1:** Since i was using AWS i had to open the port `6001` (because i was using the default port used by `laravel-websocket`, you may open whatever port you want to use) by adding an inbound rule on the EC2 Security Groups configuration.

**Step 2:** Run in ssh console the command `php artisan websocket:serve`.

**Step 3:** If you want to make sure that the process will keep running always, you can install [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

Supervisor is a client/server system which will help you to keep running the websocket server created with the command.

I hope this can help you or other developers who reach here with the same problem.

**References**

- [How To Install and Manage Supervisor](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)
- [Running Laravel Websockets in production](https://ghostscypher.medium.com/running-laravel-websockets-in-production-def368a84d56)